# Store References to Generic Repositories in UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-of-work

I am using the following **UnitOfWork** class in order to get repositories for my entities by using generics.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
  private readonly EfDbContext _context;

  public UnitOfWork()
  {
    _context = new EfDbContext();
  }

  public IRepository<T> RepositoryFor<T>() where T : Entity
  {
    return new Repository<T>(_context);
  }

  public void Save()
  {
    _context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

However, I have run into some problems where I have two separate classes that instantiate the UnitOfWork independently for a single Entity, meaning that two repositories for that Entity are created.  This causes problems with Entity Framework throwing "**An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker**" errors when I attempt save the Entity.

I am thinking that I need to more closely follow the UOW pattern as described in this **[post by Tom Dykstra](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)** under the "Creating the Unit of Work Class" section where the repository is stored in a private field and reused if existing or created if null.  The issue that I have with this is that I want my UOW to continue using generics - `Repository<T>` - and not have to declare private repository fields for all the entity types I have in my code.

How might I be able to store the fact that a repository of a given type has already been instantiated and to re-use that instead of creating a new instance of it?

**--- EDIT: Here's the fix ---**

Using Ninject, I adjusted my bindings to only instantiate a single instance of both the repositories and UOW by specifying `InRequestScope`

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>)).InRequestScope();
//kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope(); // Removed based on comment below
kernel.Bind(typeof(EfDbContext)).ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Singleton, or a factory that keeps a reference to the repository if already created, and delivers a reference or a copy or that repo

Comment: Let's say at sometime you want to have an specific query using Include() , Then the generic repository will not be enough. You may need to have a repository for that specific entity type which inherits the generic repository.

Comment: As a matter of perfection, you shouldn't register `Repository<>` in the IoC container. It's a part of a Unit of Work and it shouldn't be allowed to get it somehow except from a UoW instance. Moreover, you instantiate it explicitly rather than resolve from the container. So, registering it in the container doesn't make sense.

Comment: That makes sense.  I removed the binding for the Repository.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in multiple repositories, but in multiple `DbContext` instances. EF tells you that you can't add the same entity instance to  multiple contexts at once. So sharing repositories won't help. Moreover, having multiple UoW sharing singleton repositories is the road to hell. It will be very difficult to handle concurrency (EF isn't thread-safe), state, etc.

To fix the issue you should do either:

1. share Units of Work so that you use the same instance of UoW (and `DbContext`) throughout a single business operation
2. create copies of entity instances before adding them to another UoW.

The choice depends on your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks Pavel... your comment pointed me in the right direction.  I found the issue.  Using Ninject, I added InRequestScope and it fixed the problem.  I have updated my question with the working solution.  I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This approach usually works fine. However, there are certain limitations. For example, you might eventually need to use different UoW (different transactions) in a single server method. In such cases consider using parametrization instead of request scoping for precise control over UoW sharing.

Answer (score 0):

what do you think about this solution?

```
public class UnitOfWork
    {
        private IRepository<Animal> _animalRepository;
        public IRepository<Animal> Animals => _animalRepository ??= new Repository<Animal>();

        public IRepository<T> Repository<T>()
        {
            var result = GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .FirstOrDefault(r => typeof(IRepository<T>) == r.PropertyType)?
                .GetValue(this, null);

            return (IRepository<T>)result;
        }
    }
```